# How to terminate UIViewController

Tags: iphone, sdk, uiviewcontroller

I have two UIViewController, main and secondary, there is a button in main ViewController to view secondary's view:

```
myView = [[secondView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubView:myView.view];
```

How can I terminate secondary ViewController? if I use: `[secondView.view removeFromSuperview]`, this one will only hide UIView and keep ViewController allocated.

Due to my project design and code, I cannot use `[self presentModalViewController:myView animated:NO];`

Any solutions?

Comment: You are not supposed to nest viewController's like this (unless you really understand the mechanics of `UIViewController`'s and even then you are asking for a painful experience)

Answer (score 0):

in your case ,

```
[myView.view removeFromSuperview];
[myView release];
```

Answer (score 0):

You not need to terminate main view controller. Main View controller will become active when you remove secondary view controller, secondary view controller will terminate now.